# Подсчет количества вызовов функций с помощью декоратора

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

Парни помогите разобраться в декораторе, дали домашку для ознакомления но очень тяжко идет это все.

Написать декоратор `call_times`, который будет принимать в качестве параметра `file_name`, считать количество вызовов функций и записывать в файл в формате `f'{func_name} была вызвана {count} раза.\n'`

Пример:

```
@call_times('foo.txt')
def foo():
  pass

@call_times('foo.txt')
def boo():
  pass

@call_times('calls.txt')
def doo():
  pass

foo()
boo()
foo()
foo()
boo()
doo()
```

Файл foo.txt:

```
foo была вызвана 3 раза
boo была вызвана 2 раза
```

Файл calls.txt:

```
doo была вызвана 1 раза
```

Все работает как надо, всем спасибо ребята.

```
counter = {}
text = 'Function {} was called {} times.\n'

def call_times(file_name):
    def inner(func):
        def wrapper():
          wrapper.count += 1
          counter[func.__name__] = wrapper.count
          with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
               for func_name, quantity in counter.items():
                  f.write(text.format(func_name, quantity))
          return func()
        wrapper.count = 0
        return wrapper
    return inner

@call_times('foo.txt')
def foo():
    pass

@call_times('foo.txt')
def boo():
    pass

@call_times('calls.txt')
def doo():
    pass

for i in range(5):
    foo()

for i in range(10):
    boo()

dict.clear(counter)

for i in range(15):
    doo()
```

Comment: В чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: Без ваших попыток нельзя. Таковы правила. Возьмите какой-нибудь готовый декоратор и начните плясать от него.

Comment: а в какой момент должно это все писаться в файл? или непрерывно его обновлять?

Comment: @splash58 Да ещё и два декоратора пишут в один файл, как-то это странно )

Comment: @CrazyElf это даже ладно - это параметр, тут уж как захотят, так и вызовут

Comment: @splash58 Просто если декоратор перезаписывает файл целиком и не заботится о других декораторах, то они будут по очереди файл перетирать %)

Comment: Ну да, либо парсить файл и находить свои данные

Comment: @splash58 Не, ну это какой-то изврат. Проще всего дописывать в файл по строчке с текущим счётчиком, конечно, тогда они не подерутся

Comment: @CrazyElf Годится. Это не противоречит заданию - там не написано, что должна быть одна строка на функцию - это мои девичьи грезы :)

Comment: Спасибо вставил и код выровнялся))

Answer (score 1):

`return func()` у вас завершает работу `wrapper()`, до записи в файл дело не доходит. Нужно сначала записать в файл, потом уже выходить из функции через `return`:

```
count = 0
def call_times(file_name):
  def inner(func):
    def wrapper():
        global count
        count += 1
        with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
          f.write(f'{func.__name__} была вызвана {count} раза.\n')
        return func()
    return wrapper
  return inner
```

Но чтобы у вас считались отдельно вызовы каждой функции, а не считало общее количество вызовов, действительно нужно использовать словарь, в котором будут считаться вызовы каждой конкретной функции (ключ - функция, значение - количество вызовов):

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)


def call_times(file_name):
  def inner(func):
    def wrapper():
        counts[func] += 1
        
        with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
          f.write(f'{func.__name__} была вызвана {counts[func]} раза.\n')
        return func()
    return wrapper
  return inner
```

Comment: Если нужно чтобы выводилось в файл только один раз, а не при каждом вызове функции, то декоратор сам не должен записывать в файл, а только запоминать имя файла и считать вызовы функции, а в файл нужно писать уже при завершении программы - вручную или как-то автоматически вызвать отдельную функцию, которая полученные данные запишет в файлы.

Comment: первый случай это оно только нужно чтобы не писало вызов каждой функции отдельно а в сумме: 
foo was called 5 times, 
boo was called 10 times, 
doo was called 15 times

Comment: @AndroidTV, сегодня посмотрю, дополню ответ

Comment: Добавил строку которую забыл и все работает как надо спасибо